# gcloud "config set projectId" doesnt work

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to do some stuff in gcloud so as a first step I'm trying to set the project Id to have the available resources and permissions to work but I'm not able to get it done.
gcloud command seems to run ok, but it doesn't update projects list

[image: gcloud command seems to run ok, but it doesn't update projects list]

Even in GCP console, the "Select a Project" dropdown doesn't show the qwiklabs-gcp-xxxx as an option. Any ideas why is it happening or how can I solve it?

Comment: Is your "student_03_...." listed as project owner or editor or with any other role in the quicklabs-gpc-.... project?

Comment: If you do not see that project that means you do not have permission to access/view the project. Contact the IAM administrator who controls that Project ID. Setting the Project ID does not grant you permission, it just changes the default Project ID saved on your machine and does not affect Google Cloud.

Comment: If you want to launch qwiklabs labs it's best to open up an incognito window and log in with credentials they provide. It always worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: Thanks guys, suggestion made by John worked. I've been told it has been an ongoing issue and then they got it solved pretty quickly.